# php laravel react

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, frontend, backend

Интересуюсь созданием сборки Laravel + react(либо другой +- схожий фронтендовый фреймворк), как мне лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/frontend
там все очень подробно расписано ведь